# spell correction for foreign languages like French, Russian

Tags: php, javascript, internationalization, spell-checking

I want to implement spell correction for foreign languages like French, Russian mostly in javascript/php. In case of english spell checker, I can use edit distance algorithm to retrieve words from english dictionary (dictionary is constructed using Trie)and return highest frequency words. I also found articles on this, e.g. http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114. I think in case of foreign languages same approach can be useful.

I believe there must be API provided for different language but I don't want to introduce external dependencies of API in my application. Can someone suggest me direction, or link to any previous work done in this area. I read Peter Norvig's blog on python implementation of spell checker. But that one is for english language.

Comment: FWIW PHP has Levenshtein built-in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: have you looked into the [enchant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php) library?

Answer (score 0):

Hunspell is likely the most famous spell checker around:
http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/

There are multiple versions of hunspell, but Aspell is an alternative:
http://aspell.net/